# Dns Eligibility on Linux (.NET Core's UnicastIPAddressInformation.IsDnsEligible)

Tags: linux, networking, .net-core, dns

I am porting some windows code to linux.
The .NET Core `UnicastIPAddressInformation` class has a property named `IsDnsEligible`, which [is not implemented for Linux](https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.NetworkInformation/System/Net/NetworkInformation/UnixUnicastIPAddressInformation.cs,f99cbf4e8bd46426).

I am not familiar with networking concepts, in linux there is no way to obtain this piece of information ?

> [`IsDnsEligible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.unicastipaddressinformation?view=netcore-3.1):
> Gets a Boolean value that indicates whether the Internet Protocol (IP) address is valid to appear in a Domain Name System (DNS) server database. (Inherited from IPAddressInformation)

**Update (thanks to dratenik)**

> **Remarks**: Addresses in the range 169.254.0.0 to 169.254.255.255 are not
> DNS eligible. These addresses are reserved for Automatic Private IP
> Addressing (APIPA).

Comment: The only thing this checks is [whether the address is in the 169.254. range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ipaddressinformation.isdnseligible?view=netcore-3.1) so you have to do that yourself?

Comment: @dratenik: thanks for that. This is weird, if it is that simple, why .NET Core's team left a throw `PlatformNotSupportedException` ? By the way the remark states that the addresses in the range 169.254.***.*** are not DNS eligible. But this does not necessarily mean that these are *all* the non dns eligible addresses.

Comment: I'm not going to speculate about their reasons. Now that you know what it does, do you actually need that information?

Comment: Right, the docs have an implication, not equivalence. Here's some other project working around the issue: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/4011/commits/da576b925e1f4fff3e05292e9e94507499edb590

Comment: If you have some windows handy, you can try what it returns on loopback, broadcast and multicast addresses. I bet it only does the != 169.254 thing.